# Django: Sum of regrouped items on template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Provided our models are:

- Project
- Payment (foreign key to Project)

View is a ListView for Payment

on template

```
{% regroup payments by project as project_list %}
{% for project in project_list %}
    {{project}}
    {{<-- HOW TO OUTPUT THE SUM OF PAYMENTS FOR EACH PROJECT -->}}
    {% for payment in project.list %}
        {{payment}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How to output the sum of payments for each project?

I can do

```
Payment.objects.filter(payer=self.request.user).order_by('-date_created').annotate(total_per_project=Sum('project__donation__amount'))
```

but total_per_project can be used only in the second for loop as

> {{payment.total_per_project}}

while I need to have it in the first one, i.e.

> {{project.total_per_project}}

Comment: Don't work with `regroup` in the first place. Make a queryset with `Project`s. Can you share your models?

Comment: Do you mean a method in model ?

Comment: I don't want to query project, the logic is to query the payment. What if I also want to accomplish a search and some other functionality?

Comment: but it makes no sense to query payment. You are iterating over *projects*, not payments. Payments are here a secundary iteration. This result in inefficient queries and rendering.